# Google adsense failing to launch safari [kik]

Tags: ios, adsense, kik

Looking into a falloff in clickthroughs I noticed that Google ads are not redirecting out to safari.

Tapping on the arrow brings up a "Visit site" message.

[image]

Tapping that causes the app to reload and fail instead of opening safari.

[image]

Anyone found a solution for this issue?

Comment: how can one reproduce the issue ?